# Qt cannot find dll, though everything is set

Tags: qt, dll, error-handling, gdb, runtime-error

When I start my program it crashes (I made an earlier Post about a very simple program: [Programm crashes when QTcpServer is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270960/programm-crashes-when-qtcpserver-is-called/34291322?noredirect=1#comment56326296_34291322))

**The problem**

Running the programm with GDB it immediately exits with the following messages:

```
The GDB process terminated unexpectedly (exit code 0).
```

and

```
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135
```

Which means a .dll is missing. Running the program outise of QtCreator, a message pops up that tells me `QtNetwork4.dll is missing`

**What I did to solve**

- The code is shown in the link mentioned above, as you can see there
  I've included `QT += network` to the the projects .pro-file.
- Then I copied that *missing* .dll from the Qt-install directory
  directly to the same folder as the .exe of my program.
- I also appended to my PATH the directory where the .dll is located in
  the QT-install dir.

Still I'm getting the message that the QtNetwork4.dll is missing, and right now I'm running out of ideas. Somebody knows whats going on?

Kind Regards

Comment: have u run qmake after make changes? Try to clean, run qmake and build again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry to bother you, was my mistake he was looking for `QtNetwork4d.dll` I missed the *d* thanks for your support